# CNAME: does a cname change the url that the browser displays?

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, dns-servers, cname

I have a web site `www.somewhere.com` and I want the alias `fr.somewhere.com`.

I set up a CNAME record for `www.somewhere.com` alias `fr.somewhere.com`.  When a user types in `http://fr.somewhere.com` in their browser, does the URL in the browser remain `fr.somewhere.com` or change to `www.somewhere.com`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It will remain `fr.somewhere.com` by default but it will arrive at the server that handles `somewhere.com` requests. Inside there, in server's `.htaccess`, the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable will contain `fr.somewhere.com` for such requests. You can base your resource mapping on that.

If you would want to rewrite it to `somewhere.com`, you can simply do it like this in `.htaccess.` as well.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =fr.somewhere.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somewhere.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Note, that `%{HTTP_HOST}` will actually be `fr.somewhere.com` and if that condition matches, it will redirect (HTTP 301) to `www.somewhere.com` an append the path `$1`.

I have a CNAME record created for `blog.legoservices.com` which just points to tumblr, but all you see is `blog.legoservices.com`.